# Sliding balls on a 4x4 grid

Tags: visual, strategy, reachability

You are playing a game on the following 4x4 grid. Each turn you can slide **all** the orange balls into one of four directions: left, up, right or down. A ball will continue sliding along a direction until it hits a wall (solid blue squares), boundary of the grid or another ball. All the balls move at once. Walls do not move. Can you get the balls to finish on the target (T) cells?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the starting position the moves

> down, left, up, right

are forced. All other moves either do nothing or repeat an earlier position.

From there, we can get to the T squares with

> up, left, down, right, up, right, down, left

and we finish with both balls on the target cells.

Comment: Correct and well done! I will need to make a harder version for you.

Comment: See this: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115297/sliding-balls-on-a-4x4-grid-version-2